# Android not encoding the url as per my requirement

Tags: android, url-encoding

I have following

```
username amit24+1@gmail.com
```

how "+" is encoded as %2B

encoded url is :http://test.in/api/voi/login?password=anshu&username=amit24%2B1@gmail.com

secondly if username is this amit24*1@gmail.com then how we encode this url ?

I had tried like this :

```
 String url=ConstantNet.URL_LOGIN+ "?password=" + password.getText().toString() + "&username=" + email_mobile.getText().toString();
            String encodedurl = null;
            try {
               encodedurl = URLEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8");
                Log.e("urlEncoded",""+encodedurl);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Result i am getting from encoded url is like this :

```
https%3A%2F%2Fgoturbo.in%2Fapi%2Fvo%2Flogin%3Fpassword%anshu%26username%3Damit%2B1%40gmail.com
```

but the actual result i want like this :

```
http://test.in/api/voi/login?password=anshu&username=amit24%2B1@gmail.com
```

Comment: Is it compulsory to use get method? if there is way to send data on post method, that will solve your problem.

Comment: maybe try to replace: + with: '+'

Comment: I have to use get method only , I went through this link but not pretty sure how i will work around it :http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php

Comment: @Roish it's username , i can use if(string.contains("+")) then replace '+' with %2B, but this is not the best way to do , if user contain special character then how do i encode that string

Comment: @BarnaliBhattacharjee oh.. you'r asking about all special character?

Comment: Simply use `URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");` or use `.replace()` method for string

Comment: @BarnaliBhattacharjee: have look below code, hope that will work.

Comment: ok guys i am looking into it

Comment: @Piyush  used your code it simply replace + sign from the url , that i not need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check below code.

```
String userName = "amit24*1@gmail.com";
    String password = "anshu";
    try {

        String encodePassword = Uri.encode(password);
        String encodeUserName = Uri.encode(userName);
        android.util.Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: " + String.format("http://test.in/api/voi/login?password=%s&username=%s", encodePassword, encodeUserName));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: @BarnaliBhattacharjee : you are welcome, thanks for upvote, you can mark as right if your problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static String encodeUrl(String url)
{
    String encoded="";
    for(String i:Uri.parse(url).getQuery().split("&"))
        encoded+=(i.split("=")[0]+"="+ URLEncoder.encode(i.split("=")[1])+"&");
    return Uri.parse(url).getScheme()+Uri.parse(url).getSchemeSpecificPart()+encoded;
}
```